# Count cells but do NOT count cells with a specific partial string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I would like to start by saying, I did see similar questions out there; however, they count the cell if it does contain a partial string. I am not good enough to flip that version of the formula.

What am I using it for? I would have an excel page that would look similar to this:

```
Classroom 1    
32523    
24634    
67457    
43636    
35467

Classroom 2    
34563    
64746    
79877    
23456

Classroom 3    
23777    
36434    
23526    
68997    
36346    
34634    
74567    
58867
```

The goal here would be two things. One,I want to count all items in this column that do NOT contain the word "Classroom" and the second thing I want to accomplish (if possible, this may be too much) if I could count each classroom separately. What I mean is, these column vary in size and its a new document sent to me each month. I really would like a formula that would return with: Classroom 1 = 5, Classroom 2 = 4, etc. I have over 80 classrooms and cannot continue using one formula per class as it is incredibly time consuming to readjust the ranges. (because range size varies, I have not found a better way).

Can anyone help? I am over whelmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Total:

```
=COUNT(A:A)
```

For each classroom, make a list in order that they appear in Column A then use this in the first cell next to the first classroom and copy down. No helper column needed.

```
=COUNT(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C3,A:A,0)+1):INDEX(A:A,IFERROR(MATCH(C4,A:A,0)-1,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Going to put this as an answer since you have a 2 part question and it's hard to fit all of this into a comment

**Part 1:** One,I want to count all items in this column that do NOT contain the word "Classroom"

This part is pretty straightforward. This will count all your non-classroom ones:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A22, LEN("Classroom")) <> "Classroom"))
```

However, it will count blanks (so your example data would be 19). If you *don't* want to count blanks:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A22, LEN("Classroom")) <> "Classroom") * (A1:A22 <> ""))
```

This will return 17.

Basically, these 2 formulas work by taking the arrays you give them, and then comparing each value to see whether it's equal to classroom or blank. It counts those as 0, and anything else as a 1, and then sums up the resulting array of 0's and ones.

Next, **part 2:** I really would like a formula that would return with: Classroom 1 = 5, Classroom 2 = 4

Easiest way to do this is to add a helper column. Supposing your data starts in A2, use the following:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,9)="Classroom", A2 = ""), "",LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(A$1:A2, 9)="Classroom"),A$1:A2))
```

This formula just works by checking everything at or above it, and creating an array of TRUE/FALSE (1/0) for whether or not it's a classroom. Then, when you reach the end, you try and find a 2 in an array of 1s and 0s. Obviously you can't, so it defaults to the last value less than itself. This is the last 1 (last classroom). The index then gives the location of that classroom record and prints it.

Then, you can just use countif on your helper column, so we can count it partitioned by classroom. Supposing you have classroom 1 in in f1, classroom 2 in f2, and so on -

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$22, F1)
```

Screenshot below, although for some reason I can't get it to embed as a link

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: That is perfect. You nailed it. Thank you!

Comment: @jallington Glad to hear it :) Have a good one

Comment: I know this may be too much, but is it possible to make the second formula =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$22, F1) only count each cell once? So not counting duplicates more than one time.

Comment: @Jallington can you give an example of an input and an output you'd want to see? =SUM(IF($B$2:$B$22=F$3,1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$22,F3, $A$2:$A$22, $A$2:$A$22))) (press ctrl+shift+enter) would count duplicates within each classroom only once, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: That is, that will work perfect!

Answer (score 0):

First add a helper column to show which Classroom a line relates to.  Assuming data is in Column `A` starting at `A2` put this formula in `B2` and copy down for all data rows.  You can hide this column, or put it off to the right

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,9)="Classroom",A2,B1)
```

Formula to count all data points

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>",A:A,"<>Classroom*")
```

Put a list of Classrooms in a column, say column `C`.  In cell `D2` put this formula and copy down

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,C2,A:A,"<>",A:A,"<>Classroom*")
```

[image]